# UltiSnips snippet for automatic subscript

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I stole Gilles Castel's snippet for [automatic subscript](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/#sub--and-superscripts), and I tried to extend it to automatically subscript an i or j that follows any character. Here is my attempt

```
snippet '([A-Za-z])(?:\d|[ij])' "auto subscript" wrA
`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`_`!p snip.rv = match.group(2)`
endsnippet
```

This throws

```
IndexError: no such group
Executed snippet code: 
  1 > snip.rv = match.group(2)
  2
```

I do not know any Python, but I am hoping that this isn't a very tricky issue to solve. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `(?:...)` makes the second sub-expression [anonymous](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-17) (you can't grab it with `match.group`).

I would try:

```
snippet '([A-Za-z])(\d|[ij])' "auto subscript" wrA
`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`_`!p snip.rv = match.group(2)`
endsnippet
```

Comment: Yes, that works exactly as hoped. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If the solution works don't forgetting to validate it using v button next to the arrow voting buttons such that it can rest ;-)

Comment: This broke my green tick and upvote virginity!